# Cant delete an array/vector in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, delete-operator

I have problems deleting an array

```
int calc_mode (vector<int> array, int arrSize) { 
  int ipRepetition = new int[arrSize];
  int j;
  bool bFound;

  for(int i =0; i<arrSize; i++) {
    ipRepetition [i] = 0;
    j=0;
    bFound = false;
    while ( j<i && array[i] != array[j] ) {
      if(array[i] != array[j]) {
        ++j;        
      }   
    }
  }

  int iMaxRepeat = 0;
  for(int i =0; i<arrSize; i++)  {
    if(ipRepetition[i] > ipRepetition[iMaxRepeat] ) {
      iMaxRepeat = i;
    }  
  }

  delete [] ipRepetition; //compiler is complaining here
  return array[iMaxRepeat];
}
```

Error : Cannot delete 'ipRepetition' ....Can you please point out what I missed?

Comment: Note that the code doesn't do anything with `ipRepetition` except stuff 0's into it and test its contents. The test will always fail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int ipRepetition = new int[arrSize];
```

It's not correct. `ipRepetition` must be pointer.

```
int* ipRepetition = new int[arrSize];
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the best answer is to unask the question. Instead of hand-allocating that array of int, use another `vector<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `int*` instead of an `int`.

```
int* ipRepetition = new int[arrSize];
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with @Pete Becker's (IMO, excellent) suggestion, I'd consider using some standard algorithms to do most of the work. `std::mismatch` can tell you each location where a run ends (i.e., where a value in the input is not equal to the previous value). Along with `std::distance` (or just subtraction, since you're using random access iterators) that will tell you the length of each run fairly directly.

Once you've found the run lengths, you can use `std::max_element` to find the longest of them.